# Attiny10 with RSTDISBL and USBAsp

Tags: avr, programming, attiny

I have some project what requires all GPIO pins of attiny10 so I have to program RSTDISBL fuse. But only programmer I have is low voltage USBasp (with latest firmware supporting TPI interface).

The datasheet offers the way to re-program attiny10 by applying +12V to RST when RSTDISBL are programmed:

```
15.3.1. Enabling
The following sequence enables the Tiny Programming Interface:
• Apply 5V between VCC and GND
• Depending on the method of reset to be used:
– Either: wait tTOUT (see System and Reset Characteristics) and then set the RESET pin low.
This will reset the device and enable the TPI physical layer. The RESET pin must then be
kept low for the entire programming session
– Or: if the RSTDISBL configuration bit has been programmed, apply 12V to the RESET pin.
The RESET pin must be kept at 12V for the entire programming session
```

The USBAsp programmer doesn't supports 12V operation but I assume I could use simple inverting (because at normal operation it pulls logic low during programming and I need to pull it up to +12V) level shifter for this?

[image: circuit]

Should a circuit like this work? RST_OUT are RST pin from USBasup while RST_IN are RESET pin of ATtiny10.

Another question here is about the common ground. +5V are coming from Vusb via USBasp and +12V are coming from some sort of other PSU. Is it acceptable to combine grounds here? Or is is better to get +12V from PC PSU (same where Vusb comes from)?

Comment: MOSFETs aren't BJTs. You don't need R3 and probably don't need R2. Are you programming in-circuit? Or will this be an external programmer?

Comment: Gate biasing should not be necessary. This idea could work, if the timing of the RST_OUT coincides with the RST_IN timing needed. Check the signals with an oscilloscope beforehand.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, R3 are supposed to limit excess current during MOSFET capacitor charge. Aren't that is usually a good to have one? And R2 are here to drive M1 open while programmer keeps RST_OUT at Hi-Z state (I'm not sure here, but most likely it will when programming aren't taking place). MCU will programmed externally.

Comment: Your gate is only 110pF, and is a tiny logic level MOSFET. There is no point putting a current limit resistor as the current isn't going to be any higher than compared with a standard CMOS input. Besides, usually a current limit resistor for a MOSFET would be sub 10 Ohm. Hence the comment about not being a BJT. On top of that, your current combination of 10k-1k would give you a logic low of >0.5V at the gate which would barely turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using this as an external programming circuit (rather than inline with your existing circuitry), I see no reason why it shouldn't work if you make the following changes:

- Remove R3 - it is not helping you, and may well result in the MOSFET never turning off - this is because R2/R3 form a potential divider giving >0.5V at the gate when `RST_OUT` is low, which may not be enough margin to fully switch off a MOSFET of 0.7V Vgs(th). Current limiting is not needed for a tiny MOSFET like this.
- Ensure the 12V supply GND is common with the programmer GND. Otherwise it won't work properly. There is no danger making a common ground like this (*).

Make sure that R1 is rated for 0.25W (or higher). It will dissipate about 0.15W when not programming.

---

(*) Assuming you are using a sensible power supply.